# Dropdown menu values in button

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a drop-down menu I want to display the values in the button on the base of value selected from the list.. Screenshot is attached for reference. What is the best approach to do this?

```
<button 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-fit-height grey-salt dropdown-toggle" 
    data-toggle="dropdown" 
    data-hover="dropdown" 
    data-delay="1000" 
    data-close-others="true">

        //Where Value 1 is written I want the li values..
        Value 1
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="margin-right:15px" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Value 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Value 2</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Value 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Value 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Value 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Value 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: so what is your question? Your markup doesn't give much of an  indication of what your issue is

Comment: my question is you can see in the screenshot in the grey button there it is written Value 1 which is static value i want to display different values here on the basis of what is selected from the dropdown..

Comment: in future please provide such explanations as `expected behavior`

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$(function() {
    var $button = $('button'); // maybe better give it an id or something

    $('.dropdown-menu.pull-right a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $button.text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

But you have to make a valid HTML (button has to be closed)

Comment: Well - not the li. But you could give the button and the ul one